# My Docker image for a Ruby on Rails web API doesn't build a container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, centos7

I built a Docker image to run a web API for GA4 consulting. It works fine on my development machine, but on production (centos 7 server), it fails to build the image and returns this error:

```
[+] Building 202.3s (8/10)                                       docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 308B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.1.2              0.3s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.1.2@sha256:7681a3d37560dbe8ff7d0a  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.65kB                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./                              0.0s
 => ERROR [4/6] RUN gem install bundler:2.2.28                           201.8s
------
 > [4/6] RUN gem install bundler:2.2.28:
121.3 ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 2.2.28), here is why:
121.3           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
------
dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
   6 |
   7 | >>> RUN gem install bundler:2.2.28
   8 |     RUN bundle install
   9 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c gem install bundler:2.2.28" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]`
```

when running the command:

```
docker build -t api .
```

I get the previous error.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: i'm sorry for this, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your docker container on your production server is not able to access the internet or at least a DNS for domain name résolution thus the error message.
Can your physical server access internet? If yes, then check why your docker container is isolated from the internet (look for docker networking)

Cheers

Comment: thanks, i got this running: "docker build -t api --network host ."